# How to share methods between rails sidekiq workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two sidekiq workers in a rails app and I'm wondering what the best way to share code between them would be.

```
class PriceReminderWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: 'price_alerts'

  def method_to_share
    stuff
  end 
end
```

and

```
class PriceNotificationWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: 'price_alerts'

  def method_to_share
    stuff
  end 
end
```

Would the 'rails/ruby way' to be inherit from a parent class, or add a new module perhaps?

Comment: This is a very generic question.  Sometimes inheritance makes sense, sometimes including or extending via a module makes sense, and sometimes injecting an object with the method(s) might make sense (aka strategy pattern).  Perhaps you can provide more details, such as what the shared method does and how it relates to both classes.

Comment: @nPn probably just showing them an example of inheritance and including a module would answer the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use inheritance if it makes sense to you for example that `PriceReminderWorker` and `PriceNotificationWorker` are both a `PriceWorker` and the methods you want to share make sense in the `PriceWorker` context.  For example in Rails it makes sense that all Models are an `ApplicationRecord`

I would include the methods in a Module, if the methods you want to share merely take advantage of some common "trait" that both classes share.  For example in Ruby both the Array class and the Hash class share a "trait", they both implement a `foreach` method that can accept a block and call that block for each member of its collection.  In this case both classes include the `Enumerable` module.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your shared methods in a module and just include them into your worker classes.

```
module Workify
  def method_to_share
    puts "hooray we're DRY!"
  end
end

class PriceReminderWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: 'price_alerts'
end

class PriceNotificationWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: 'price_alerts'
end
```

Both worker classes now have access to the method defined in the module.